# Как проверить нажатие кнопки aiogram?

Tags: python, aiogram

Есть список, который выводится в виде inline кнопок. Возможно ли сделать проверку на нажатие этой кнопки и вывода её названия?

```
l = ['Яблоки', 'Бананы']
            keyboard = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
            backbutton = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Назад", callback_data="MainMenu")
            button_list = [types.InlineKeyboardButton(text=name, callback_data=name) for name in l]
            keyboard.add(*button_list)
            await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Выбери фрукт:', reply_markup=keyboard)
```

Comment: Да, вы можете фильтровать через lambda функцию и использовать модуль re для поиска совпадений. Например все callback будут ['fruit-apple', 'fruit-pie', ...] тогда для вызова handler на фрукты: re.search('fruit-', c.data)

Comment: Здравствуйте! Большое спасибо за ваш ответ! Но я не до конца понял, как мне прописать это в @dp.callback_query_handler!

Comment: Насколько я помню там есть параметр func. Пример: `@dp.callback_query_handler(func=lambda c: re.search('fruit-', c.data))`

Comment: Спасибо большое! Вы мне очень помогли! :)

Answer (score 1):

Решение оказалось вот таким (Большое спасибо за это [artemgh](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/423786/artemgh))

```
@dp.callback_query_handler(lambda c: re.search('fruit-', c.data))
async def writeLesson(call: CallbackQuery):
    name_lesson = call.data.split("-")[1]
    await call.message.answer(text=name_lesson)
```